# Server monitoring System

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, nagios, elasticsearch-marvel, kibana-5

Hi I have five production server for(website,Cassandra,elastic search,redis) and I want to monitor them so I came across many monitoring tools and I finalized the two tools

```
1. Nagios
2. ElasticSearch Beats
```

Now I am not able to get which one to use.So which one will give me better system stats and is more scalable and easy to configure and use.

Comment: I think this question is out of the scope of SO, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also it's elastic beats, from the company developing them (and you should have asked which beat you wanted to compare to nagios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Better" is, of course, subjective.

Both nagios and metricbeat can give you the basic information about the machine (disk space, load, etc).

Nagios can be tough to configure, but runs well once it's setup.  I find it to be cloud "unfriendly" as the configuration is centralized.  I've had to jump through hoops to make it work decently in AWS.

Metricbeat has 9 different things it can send (including plugins for MySQL, etc). Nagios has countless plugins.

While nagios still needs a central server, I would say that it's easier to run than an elasticsearch cluster.

But, if you have log files, then using the Elastic stack can be a good foundation.

You might take a look at sensu, which is easier to configure and can run all the nagios plugins.  Using both sensu and metricbeat in combination would also work well.